# How to pass a reactive object with prop values from a component to a composable in vue3 / nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-reactivity

i have a vue component using the composition API that has some `props` passed into it.

i would like this component to pass its props into a composable that's a wrapper around `useFetch`, and i would like the composable to retain reactivity when the component's props change. i.e. i want `useFetch` to re-run when the props change.

**the following works when i explicitly pass the props in as refs to the composable.**

*component:*

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps({
    page: {
      default: 1,
      required: false,
      type: Number,
    },
    search: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  });

  const { data, error, pending } = await useGetData(toRef(props, 'page'), toRef(props, 'search'));
</script>
```

*composable:*

```js
export default (page: Ref<number>, search: Ref<string>) => {
  const limit = ref(20);
  const offset = computed(() => {
    const p = page.value || 1;
    return (p > 1) ? ((p - 1) * limit.value) : 0;
  });

  return useLazyFetch<DataIndex>('/api/data', {
    query: {
      limit,
      offset,
      search,
    },
    deep: false,
  });
});
```

now, i would like to pass the props to my composable as an *object* instead of an ordered set of arguments. when i do this i seem to lose reactivity on the props - i.e. the query doesn't re-run when the props change in my component.

**i've tried various interations of attempting to pass the props in as refs, but have had no luck.**

*component:*

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps({
    page: {
      default: 1,
      required: false,
      type: Number,
    },
    search: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  });
  const dataInput = reactive({
    page: props.page,
    search: props.search,
  });
  const { data, error, pending } = await useGetData(toRefs(dataInput));
</script>
```

*composable:*

```js
interface GetDataInput {
  page?: Ref<number>
  search?: Ref<string>
};

export default (input: GetDataInput) => {
  const limit = ref(20);
  const offset = computed(() => {
    const p = input.page?.value || 1;
    return (p > 1) ? ((p - 1) * limit.value) : 0;
  });

  return useLazyFetch<DataIndex>('/api/data', {
    query: {
      limit,
      offset,
      search: input.search,
    },
    deep: false,
  });
});
```

i assume that i'm losing reactivity in this example because either `dataInput` is not seeing the prop change, or because the `input` argument itself is not reactive when passed into the composable.

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is using `defineProps` in the wrong way.

`defineProps` will return a reactive object (a `Proxy`), means `props` is now reactive. Since you declare a new `reactive` with your `props.x`. `dataInput` is a new reactive object that is initialized with value of `props.x` (just value initialization, no reactivity here)

That's why when `props` is changed, `dataInput` is kept intact cause they are not related or connected. Try to use `toRefs(props)` instead

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps({
    page: {
      default: 1,
      required: false,
      type: Number,
    },
    search: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  });
  //const dataInput = reactive({
  //  page: props.page,
  //  search: props.search,
  //});
  const { data, error, pending } = await useGetData(toRefs(props));
</script>
```

And for some reason, if you still want to keep `dataInput`, try this instead

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps({
    page: {
      default: 1,
      required: false,
      type: Number,
    },
    search: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  });
  const dataInput = reactive(toRefs(props));
  const { data, error, pending } = await useGetData(toRefs(dataInput));
</script>
```

Comment: aha! that makes sense, and both of those work.

the reason that i'd like to use `dataInput` is to keep my composable flexible and reusable by components that may have different `props` or `refs` that i want to pass in.

so, as long as the calling component's `props` keys match the `dataInput` interface's keys, i should be fine to add other attributes with a spread operator (e.g. `dataInput = reactive({someRef, ...toRefs(props)});`).